# How to detect whether a list view changed or a list changed from getting data from an HTML file?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I can detect when an HTML file downloaded has been updated and update a list with the data I extracted from the HTML file every 1 second, but how can I check if the list or list view changed the order or was updated?

```
 public async Task StartWebCrawl()
    {

        var url = "http://challonge.com/jex0ymd2/standings";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
        List<String> listStandings = new List<string>();
        var participants = new List<Particpants>();





        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                // Do the actual request and wait for it to finish.
                await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

                // Switch back to the UI thread to update the UI
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    // Update the UI
                    var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("left display_name"))
                    .ToList();

                    foreach (var div in divs)
                    {

                        var participant = new Particpants
                        {
                            TeamName = div.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().InnerText

                        };

                        participants.Add(participant);

                    }
                    foreach (var name in participants)
                    {
                        listStandings.Add(name.TeamName);
                    }
                    ListView.ItemsSource = listStandings;

                    List<String> newlistStandings = new List<String>(listStandings);
                    if (HasChanged(listStandings, newlistStandings))
                    {
                        DisplayAlert("S", "S", "h");

                    }


                    // Now repeat by scheduling a new request
                    StartWebCrawl();

                });

            });

            // Don't repeat the timer (we will start a new timer when the request is finished)

            return false;
        });

    }

    public bool HasChanged(List<string> listStandings, List<string> newListStandings)
    {
        if (listStandings.Count != newListStandings.Count)
        {
            return true;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < listStandings.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listStandings[i] != newListStandings[i])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: you need to keep a copy of the data, and then compare the new data to the old

Comment: you can do this in two ways
create a global variable and increase the count when list is updated and check the variable and check against it. (or)
you can create a variable save it in a session and increase the count when list is updated and check against it.

Answer (score 0):

You would compare them, by keeping a copy of the old list, then comparing it to the new list. Also I would probably change from an ObservableCollection to a List, since you aren't actually ever going to change the collection, you keep creating a new one each time.

```
    public bool HasChanged(ObservableCollection<string> listStandings, ObservableCollection<string> newListStandings)
    {
        if (listStandings.Count != newListStandings.Count)
            return true;

        for (int i = 0; i < listStandings.Count; i++)
            if (listStandings[i] != newListStandings[i])
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I added your code but how do I keep a copy of the old list to compare? I tried:      List<String> newlistStandings = new List<String>(listStandings);